# Submitting form including file upload to ASP.NET webform from HTML or MVC view

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, forms, webforms

there is a ASP.NET webform app in use and I should upgrade most of it to MVC (specifically Umbraco 7 CMS that is MVC-based).

Since most of the business logic is written in webforms, my question is - can I somehow collect data - and most important, input file data - in HTML form (or MVC view to be exact) and submit it to the existing webform?

Those webforms have their own web controls and round trips, dealing with submission on postback, in a classic way. I guess I could rewrite most of the code to accept Request.Form without postback (CORS is not the issue since it's hosted on the same server)...

But how to manage the file upload since webforms use FileUpload web control?

(One webform is written in C# and the other in Visual Basic, but I guess I will manage to "translate" it once I get the solution...)

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can embed ASP.NET Webforms in MVC and and MVC in Webforms - at least if 'one rules the request'. Neither of which are pretty. However, the logic in the webforms itself cannot be easily moved to MVC, excepting as a proper port - and the very structure of which should be examined. The FileUpload control also uses a postback via the normal form/multi-part upload mechanisms.

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly advise you to take this opportunity to extract out your business logic into at least a separate set of independent C# files, best case being a project that you've got other business logic in (or a new one).

You really don't want to be dependent upon logic inside user controls when you're actually moving away from Web Forms. Take the extra development time up front and it'll save you lots of time and headaches in the long run.

Comment: Thank you, I am aware of that. However, can you help me out?